# Doesn't appear the selected option in <select>

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to create dynamically some check-boxes in my `django` project, what I'm doing is:

```
<form action="#" method="post" target="#">
    {% for node in Last_val_nodes %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{node.0}}" value="#" class="nodos_check_ruta"> {{node.0}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Where `Last_val_nodes` is a list of lists that comes from my `views.py` and I'm interested in the first value of this "sublists". Up to this point all is good, but now what I want to do is know what `checkbox` is selected. That's why I'm writing in name `{{node.0}}`, because my `js` do the next,

```
if( $('.nodos_check_ruta').is(':checked') ) {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    alert(name);
}
```

But the alert is undefined. Who can I know the selected check-boxes? If there more than one selected, how can I know it? I want to save all the selected in a list.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `"this"` in your example ? your `if` statement is not `jquery` statement so it doesnt give you `this` that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to read

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

This way you will iterate over checked elements

```
$('.nodos_check_ruta:checked').each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

This way you will return an array of jquery elements

```
$( '.nodos_check_ruta:checked' ).map( function( index, element ) {
  return element;
}).get();
```

Comment: Is happening the same, with the first code is appearing `0:`, `1:`,`2:` i snot appearing `$( this ).text()`

Comment: @NEA I just gave example how to iterate. If its checkbox then it doesn't have text I guess. So propably you can get values of attributes using `.val()` or `attr()` . I thought its irrelevent since you want to get `jquery element`, or did I miss something ? Let me know if you still need help.